# Create trigger in Oracle DB to provide the fixed length for an individual column

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Create trigger on the table Employees, which should:

Trigger on the data insertion command
Format the **`phone`** field, converting it to the pattern **`(YYY)XXX-XX-XX`**. The number you enter must be **10** digits. The trigger should check for this. If the number has *less than or more than* **10** *digits*, then prohibit data insertion and issue an error message.

Tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dept
(
  dept_id    number(3) not null,
  dept_name  varchar2(50) not null,
  emp_cnt    number(3) not null,
  constraint dept_pk primary key (dept_id)
);
/
CREATE TABLE employees
(
  emp_id   number(3) not null,
  dept_id  number(3) not null,
  emp_name varchar2(50) not null,
  address  varchar2(100),
  phone    varchar2(20) not null,
  salary   number(8,2) not null,
  constraint emp_pk primary key (emp_id),
  constraint dept_fk foreign key (dept_id) references dept(dept_id)
);
/
```

Please, help me

Comment: MySQL does not support VARCHAR2. Check your DBMS carefully.

Comment: *you should be using Oracle DB which's obvious from the data type `varchar2` and the slash after the statement*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CHECK constraint will not solve your problem as you have to mask your Phone, which will ultimately have more than 10 digits. So you have to put a check condition in your TRIGGER. For masking the phone number in the desired format, You can use the below trigger -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_mask_phone
BEFORE INSERT ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF LENGTH(:new.phone) <> 10 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Phone No is incorrect');
     END IF;
     :new.phone := '(' || SUBSTR(:new.phone, 1, 3) || ')' || SUBSTR(:new.phone, 4, 3) || '-' || SUBSTR(:new.phone, 7, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(:new.phone, 9, 2);
END;
/
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=69466c989148e155defa2b9fa4120205)

Comment: The check for length should be `<>10`. I agree that (otherwise) this solution meets the Seeker's needs. I think in real life we would store the phone number as a numeric, and use a function or a view to format it for display purposes.

Comment: @APC, Missed that. Updated now.